# Getting the exit status from inside an function registered with atexit()

Tags: c

Inside my **atexit()** registered function I would like to get the exit status (either the argument to **exit(3)** or what main() returned with).

Is there any portable way of doing this? Is there any GNU libc specific way of doing it such as a global holding that value I can reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hack:

```
// hack.c
int last_exit;

// hack.h
extern int last_exit;
#define exit(x) (exit)(last_exit = (x))
```

Won't work for `return`, but, hey, it's portable!

On a more maintainer-friendly note, you may want to consider writing some form of wrapper to do something similar to this for you. Hacking around how GCC implements `exit()` sounds like a maintenance nightmare. Better to write a few helper functions that exit for you, and maybe even mask them with macros if you're into that kind of thing. With a macro you might even be able to replace `return` calls, if you always call `return` with parenthesis. Though this sounds like even more of a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Thanks. Yes setting my own global before calling exit() and using that in my registered func seems like the best idea.

Comment: Remember the parenthesis around `exit` in the macro - they make sure that the macro won't try to call itself, but allow the macro to call a function of the same name. I only recently learned that trick, but it allows you to avoid making your hack clearly obvious with something like `#define EXIT(x) exit(last_exit = x)`. All-caps are just ugly.

Comment: An extra set of parentheses around `(x)` in the macro definition is advisable.

Comment: @caf - My bad. I usually do that. For what it's worth, I don't see any way it could backfire without the parenthesis - the only operator with lower precedence is `,`, which will cause a completely different (and quite catchable) problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `on_exit`. This is deprecated, and this is not Posix, but at least it is in glibc.