# Windows console app (C++) has wrong exit code

Tags: c++, windows, console

I've got a windows console app that uses the boost unit test framework and main() ends in a fairly simple exit(ret) where ret is the return from the boost framework.

Running an example I see ret as 201 but the exe return code reported by the debugger and others is 0. What can cause the return code to differ from the parameter to exit()?

Thanks.

Comment: A code example would help;)

Comment: I'd provide one if I had a simple way to reproduce it! One suggestion I found was that during the Dll unload when ExitProcess is running, an errant Dll could cause another ExitProcess (or similar) with a different exit code - but I have no idea how to check if that's the case. Obviously simple programs work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If no code can be provided, then what could be advised is to hook-up an exit callback with [std::atexit()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) and use the hack from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196917/getting-the-exit-status-from-inside-an-function-registered-with-atexit) to see if when your callback is called the exit value is still the same as in `main()`. Remember though you can't use `return` since that won't set the value, so replace that with an `exit()` call. Also, you will be able only to see the return codes of the DLL's that can build yourself and add the hack.

Also, you could call [GetExitCodeProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx), I'm not aware of the behavior if called inside and exit callback, most likely you will get the `STILL_ACTIVE` value but still worth a stot.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Sadly, the problem occurs after that hook gets called. There was a lot going on in the code so it took a while to strip it down to the minimum but I've now found out what was going on. We used TibEMS.dll and it appears that when this unloads it causes the process exit code to change to zero - no idea why but it's now reproducible in a simple test case.