# Why is there no std::on_exit?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, exit, exit-code

A program can exit with a variety of different status codes.
I'd like to bind an exit handler as a catch all way of handling final tasks based on this status code.
Is it possible to dispatch on the status code from within the exit handler?
As far as I can tell, [No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196917/getting-the-exit-status-from-inside-an-function-registered-with-atexit).

Therefore, I am unable to obtain the status value, as shown in this small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int Get_Return_Code(){
  //can this be implemented?
  return 0;
}

void Exit_Handler() {

    // how do I get the return code
    // from within the exit heandler?
    auto return_code = Get_Return_Code(); //?

    // I'd like to make decisions based on the return code
    // while inside my exit handler
    if (return_code == EXIT_SUCCESS){
      std::cout << "perform exit successful tasks...\n";
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "perform exit failure tasks...\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc,  char** argv) 
{
    //bind the exit handler routine
    if (std::atexit(Exit_Handler)){
      std::cerr << "Registration failed\n";
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //if an argument is passed, exit with success
    //if no argument is passed, exit with failure
    if (argc > 1){
      std::cout << "exiting with success\n";
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    std::cout << "exiting with failure\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Is there a reason that C++ does not yet include [on_exit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/on_exit.3.html)?
I'm concerned about cross-compatibility in the windows world.

**in regards to the code base:**
My goal for doing this, does not involve memory management. We have an existing code base. There are exit statements everywhere. When a program exits with error, I'd like to display what that error code means to the user. In my mind, this is the fastest solution without major refactoring.

Comment: Because it isn't needed? You can do the same thing righ now, simply by wrapping your code in a `try/catch/finally` block. An exit handler is required when a language doesn't have exception handling

Comment: You may be able to implement `exit()` yourself, overriding the standard library version, and have it call `_exit()` after doing whatever you want with the numeric code.  I'm not sure this is a great idea, but it might be a way to get what you want if you really must.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just `try-catch`, no `finally` needed in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza You can't catch exit statements that already exist.  I agree though, exceptions are often a better route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most portable solution would be to wrap your program inside a shell script or other program. This wrapping script or program can then check the exit code and display the appropriate message to the user.

Answer (score 9):

Because cleanup tasks are supposed to be performed by your destructors, and your code is supposed to gracefully return from any scope under all circumstances (be it via `return` or `throw`).

`at_exit` is an anti-pattern in a RAII-friendly world.

If you want to perform some logic depending on what you're about to return from `main`, simply perform it when you're about to return from `main`. In `main`.

Comment: That's fair.  My circumstances aren't really in regards to memory management.  We have an existing code base.  There are exit statements everywhere.  When a program exits with error, I'd like to display what the error code means to the user.  In my mind, this is the fastest solution without major refactoring.

Comment: what about the cases when you want to do something AFTER you return from main?

Comment: @Alex: Then you could put whatever you wanted in `main` BEFORE you return.

Comment: @Alex: You never want to do something after you return from `main`. Because then it's not really `main` anymore.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit look at embedded startup code there are platforms where hooking after main gives you advantages, because your operating system is shut down; granted it's not posix.

Comment: @Alex: Specifically supporting such environments are _well_ outside of the scope of the standard, and this question is about standard facilities.

Comment: True for a standalone program, but when you're developing a lib providing a auto-cleanup is far easier than providing a manual cleanup function and guarantees to not leave any memory leak.